# Little knots of wool on the bottom/side of the Tzitzit

Tags: minhag, tzitzis, tallit-gadol

On most Tallitot and Sephardi Tallitot Ketanot there are little knots on the bottom or side. What are they? Why are they there? What are their significance?

Comment: Makes sense. But that would mean they are largely superfluous if you wear a tallis katan with a T-opening in front.

Answer (score 1):

These knots help ensure that the front Tzitzises (which are holier) are not accidentally moved to the back.

Comment: Good answer! But what aboht Talit Gadol (unless I'm missing how it works for Talit Gadol)?

Comment: Some of the tzitzit are holier than others? How do you figure?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill I also have a request for the source for that presumption that the front ones are holier. Do you have one? And also I don't get how the Atara has to do with anything...

Comment: @DoubleAA, _tzitzis_ should stay where they were (we learn this from the _k'rashim_ (planks) of the _mishkan_, which had the same rule). (The _baal haTanya_ says it's not necessary for _tzitzis_, which is why Lubavitchers don't have _ataros_.) I don't have a citation at the moment, but will _bl"n_ try to find one.

Comment: ... _Mishna B'rura_ 8:9, and it's the _Ari_ (citied there in the _MB_), not the _baal haTanya_. @H'Gabriel, courtesy ping.

Comment: @msh210 I read I believe I read it in Ben Ish Hai citing the Ari

Comment: @msh210 Staying where they were and holier are two different things. The MB says nothing about holiness.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill I've never seen any reference to the two front ones being holier. Do you have a definite source for this?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

The threads at the end of the garment are unfinished, so they get balled up and knotted. Is that for halachic reasons or practical ones, I have no idea.

Comment: But some have them and some don't...Also, in modern times they couldn't come up with a way to make them not stick and not have to put the knots?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin The wife of the Lubavitcher rebbe did not like those knots and would cut them off. As a result Lubavitchers fold their tallis "backwards", hiding the knots under the tallis instead of having them visible on top.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I'm not sure, sorry. I was told the story only in passing to explain why the Tallis was folded under.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/why-do-lubavitchers-fold-their-talisos-under-on-the-shoulders

Comment: @Ariel - The real reason for the Lubavitchers tucking their tallis under itself is because the Lubavitcher Rebbe's father wore a white-striped tallis, and the Frierdiker Rebbe wore a black-striped tallis. Thus, the Rebbe tucked his tallis under itself to honor both minhagim.