# Are there tallit gadol without fringes?

Tags: tallit-gadol

All the traditional tallits I have seen have fringes on the sides. Are there tallits without such fringe? How traditional are they?

Comment: Your last question is asked here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12569/759